# Is there a way to see collectibles on the map?

Tags: mirrors-edge-catalyst

I've finished the main storyline and unlocked the upgrade that adds Gridleaks to the map. However, I'm still missing plenty of other collectibles (documents, recordings, bags, and especially electronic parts). The map will tell you how many are in each district, and how many you have found, but beyond that it's just needles in a haystack.

Is there any way to get the rest of the collectibles added to the map, or do I have to just search every inch of the city?

Comment: Would you like me to provide an outside source map? As in an unofficial  map with all of the collectibles on it provided by the internet?

Comment: I'm aware there are such maps (and videos) showing the location of everything, but I'm asking if there is a way to get these items to show up on the in-game map, similar to the gridleaks upgrade available after completing the main story.

Comment: Alright. I haven't played the game so any information I give if I do give may be false. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to display collectibles like documents and security recordings on the map.

Billboards, time trials, and gridleaks appear in the open world and thus appear on the map. However, security recordings, bags, and documents can be found in the game's levels which are inaccessible during free roam. Because the areas are inaccessible they do not appear on the map and the level has to be replayed to collect them again.

You mentioned collecting electronic parts; while useful, they aren't needed for a 100% completion achievement if that's what you're trying to do.